# how to use bind function when there is an attribute error (using theme)

Tags: python, attributes, themes, bind

The following code+error is a component of a logging in portal, I'm using a theme named sun valley, and I think its because of that particular reason.

```
def newWin():

    zz = tk.Tk()
    zz.title('account sign in')
    zz.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\python\Downloads\logo.ico')

    

newwindowbtn = ttk.Label(root, text="Already have an account? Just sign in then!",
                font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold')).place(x=25, y=600)

#bind label
newwindowbtn.bind("<Button-1>", newWin)
```

Output:

hyperbtn.bind("", new_window)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Answer (score 0):

Now this works fine.

This error is because you assign the `newwindowbtn` to a
`ttk.label.place()` where `place` return `None` which is cause this
error you need to assign `newwindowbtn` to `ttk.label` and in next line you can use `newwindowbtn.place(x=25, y=600)`.

```py
def newWin(e): # you can name it whatever you want. This parameter is really important.

    zz = tk.Tk()
    zz.title('account sign in')
    zz.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\python\Downloads\logo.ico')

    

newwindowbtn = ttk.Label(root, text="Already have an account? Just sign in then!",
                font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))

newwindowbtn.place(x=25, y=600)

#bind label
newwindowbtn.bind("<Button-1>", newWin)
```

Comment: @ehe this is because the bind method gives one argument to the function. I edit my code you sould take a look.

Comment: Its ok now I solved it hehe thank you for helping =>